# Eventlet + DNS Python Attribute Error: module "dns.rdtypes" has no attribute ANY

Tags: python, flask-socketio, eventlet, dnspython

I know that someone will face this problem. I had this problem today, but I could fix it promptly, and I want to share my solution:

Problem:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
```

You will receive an output error with something like:

> Attribute Error: module "dns.rdtypes" has no attribute ANY

This only happens if you have installed eventlet, because it install dnspython with it.

The solution is simple, just reinstall dnspython for previous realease:

> python3 -m pip install dnspython==2.2.1

The problem should disappear

Answer (score 15):

The solution is simple, just reinstall dnspython for previous realease:

> python3 -m pip install dnspython==2.2.1

The problem should disappear

Answer (score 4):

I suggest taking the opposite route, i.e. *upgrading* `eventlet` (to 0.33.3 at the time of this writing) rather than *downgrading* `dnspython`.